# FlatList React Native: Nested Object

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm a beginner in React Native and I need help (thank you in advance).

I need access to the data inside of a nested object to display on the FlatList (React Native).

Here is my data structure:

**Data = [{Object 1: {title: 'Object 1', owner: { name: 'Luis'}}}]**

During my renderItem I want to access the owner.name to be displayed on the row.

```
 const renderTime = ({ item }) => {
return <Card title={item.title} name={item.owner.name} />;};
```

I tried multiple ways including mapping and Object Keys, but I cannot make it work.

Thank you,

Comment: const renderTime = (item) => (<Card title={item.Object1.title} name={item.Object1.owner.name} />)

Answer (score 0):

First data is an array, so it's might be something like this :

```
Data = [
        {title: 'Object 1', owner: { name: 'Luis'}},
        {title: 'Object 1', owner: { name: 'Luis'}}
       ];

const renderTime = (item) => (<Card title={item.title} name={item.owner.name} />)
```

Since Data is an array, if you want to call *renderTime* with *Data* :

```
renderTime(Data[0])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the approach mentioned will not work because I'm passing the renderTime inside the renderItem of a FlatList that gets an item. I tried with item[index].owner.name but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: oh ! Sorry it's because if you want to get the data of item, you need to give the key :
It's renderTime(Data[0]['Object 1']);